# Ambiguous use of method speak (Nuance Speechkit)in SWIFT 3

Tags: swift, swift3, ios10, xcode8, ambiguous

Making my code compliant with Swift 3 is a headache.

I am getting this Swift Compiler error:

```
"Ambiguous use of speak(_:string:delegate)"
```

In this method that was working fine in Swift2:

```
//parameters: speak(String, String, SKTransactionDelegate)    
skTTSTransaction = skTTSSession!.speak(saythis, withLanguage: langString, delegate: self)
```

The line above uses Nuance's Speeckit framework to do Text To Speech (TTS).

```
skTTSTransaction is of type SKTransaction.
skTTSSession is of type skSession
self comes from a UIViewController that implements SKTransactionDelegate
```

I am no expert in ambiguity, what am I doing wrong?
If you need extra clues in order to help me let me know.

Comment: A tip for this kind of errors: comment your code then start writing it again and let Xcode's autosuggest guide you to the new syntax.

Comment: already tried that @EricAya

Comment: The syntax is even different in the [documentation](https://developer.nuance.com/public/Help/DragonMobileSDKReference_iOS/Speech-synthesis.html): `let transaction = session.speakString(textToSpeak, withLanguage: "eng-USA", delegate: self)` But this doesn't look like Swift 3, it's probably their old example...

Comment: Maybe the compiler imports it like this now? `session.speak(string: textToSpeak, withLanguage: "eng-USA", delegate: self)` or `session.speak(withString: textToSpeak, withLanguage: "eng-USA", delegate: self)`

Comment: The explicit parameter was not accepted, could this be a bug in Nuance's framework? @EricAya

Comment: No idea, mate. I was just trying to guess what the compiler could have done differently since it has new rules for Swift 3. Regarding your issue, at this point I would just try to contact someone from the framework and ask if/when they're ready for Swift 3.